# Visual Studio RC always jump to debugger

Tags: windows, microsoft-metro

When I buid my app, it always jump to this line of base.js without any errors. Why? How to fix?

```
var terminateAppHandler = function (data) {
    debugger;
    MSApp.terminateApp(data);
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two reasons to see this:

1. You have a promise chain ending in a done, that is experiencing an error, but you have not provided an error handle in the call to done. It is the second parameter to done, and when called its only parameter is the error info.
2. You have an unhandled exception in your application. Turn on break when exceptions are thrown in debug/exceptions in vs to break into the debugger when the exception is thrown.